# How to interpret Logistic regression coefficients using scikit learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I have created a model using Logistic regression with 21 features, most of which is binary. I created these features using get_dummies. Few of the other features are numeric. I get a very good accuracy rate when using a test set. On checking the coefficients, I am not able to interpret the results. I understand that the coefficients is a multiplier of the value of the feature, however I want to know which feature is most significant. How do I interpret by the coefficient value?

Coefficients are:

```
[[9.94670383e-01 1.11134574e+00 1.52026366e+00 1.00438802e+00
  1.00526047e+00 9.99706283e-01 1.16615129e+00 7.62542057e-01
  2.07560050e-01 6.37260544e+00 5.04481410e+01 1.25174912e+00
  1.41552939e-02 1.00212609e+00 8.99670711e-01 1.54314635e+00
  1.40966824e+00 2.59413851e+00 9.60362518e-01 7.12430063e-01
  9.49015749e-01 8.73217396e-01 1.13360003e+00 1.29499497e+00
  2.59413851e+00 8.48199127e-01 1.29459832e+00 8.39932559e-01
  6.74508365e-01 7.78038545e-01 8.47179333e-01 9.41898759e-01
  8.98000460e-01 1.00399001e+00 9.48308585e-01 9.50727965e-01
  9.44539862e-01 9.54521379e-01 9.44539862e-01 1.00399001e+00
  9.50727965e-01 9.37261117e-01 1.15132693e+00 1.45405029e+00
  1.23885045e+00 1.06559667e+00 9.81397305e-01 9.83352615e-01
  9.78351208e-01 1.00000000e+00 1.21413156e+00 1.00000000e+00
  8.22625929e-01 9.91538253e-01 9.87898964e-01 9.73726514e-01
  1.01138367e+00 9.32550966e-01 1.00415197e+00 9.82564951e-01
  1.33411399e+00 9.96881917e-01 9.07833416e-01 1.00000000e+00
  1.00288719e+00 9.84791831e-01 1.00000000e+00 9.90776061e-01
  1.30224077e+00 1.00197704e+00 1.00493857e+00 9.98820836e-01
  9.97599386e-01 9.90111246e-01 1.00026804e+00 9.99640135e-01
  9.51405033e-01 1.00719641e+00 1.01318728e+00 1.06443148e+00
  7.75383243e-01 9.52164748e-01 1.00000000e+00 1.07497387e+00
  9.93559217e-01 1.00000000e+00 9.85889880e-01 1.00800864e+00
  9.89096317e-01 1.10525575e+00 1.06559667e+00 9.99043816e-01
  1.32622212e+00 1.10525575e+00 1.00025462e+00 6.68703857e-01
  8.29126910e-01 7.54026844e-01 1.21169810e+00 1.83053934e+00
  9.90596303e-01]]
```

As most of the variables are dummy variables, how would I know which value is it being used 1/0? 
Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**Significance:** As far as I know, sklearn does not come with a module to get p-values. You could go for statsmodels:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55655645/9524424

**Interpretation:** Remember that Logit uses a logistic link function, so there is no easy on-the-go interpretation of the coefficients. You need to calculate [marginal effects](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70509/logistic-regression-and-marginal-effect), so the change in $y$ when you alter some $x$, all other things equal. Stata has such module(s). However, I think sklearn has no such implementation. Python statsmodels seems to come with an option to derive marginal effects as well, but I never tried it. Look for `.get_margeff`.

https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.DiscreteResults.get_margeff.html

Comment: N.B., p-values are "significance" (a measure of whether "the" coefficient is zero), not feature importances:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/291239/232706

Comment: As for interpretation, it's not so direct, but since the linear model is for the log-odds, you can interpret the coefficients as multiplicative effects on the odds.